# How to programmatically end an ASP.NET session after a given amount of time

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, iis-6

we're in need to stop the user session in an ASP.NET site after some time(say 20 mins).

We know we can use a timer and code every page to expire on the timer tick, but we're searching a faster way, maybe through an IIS configuration?

Is there a built in way to do such things?

We're using ASP.NET 2.0, Framework 3.5, IIS 6, c#.

TY.

ADDON: I think it's better to elaborate a bit on the question...
We want to achieve something like a "demo" mode, where a user can use the site in full mode for a bounch of minutes, then the site will be inoperable due to the elapsed "demo" time.
Hope that's clearer.

Comment: 20 minutes of idle time?  That's the default behavior ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this, for example web.config and IIS. This article explains how to use various methods for changing the timeout value.

http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2008/07/aspnet-session-timeouts.html

Comment: I red the blogEntry and it was somewhat useful in the sense that now I know that we cannot accomplish the "demo" thing via configuration.

Answer (score 1):

This might answer your question:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1283350.aspx